# ffplay works from command line but error with .sh script and systemd

Tags: ffmpeg, shell-script, systemd

(Originally posted as a generic question, then I found the ffplay forum)

I'm trying to set up a daemon to play short sound effects as part of an interactive wheelchair ride. (Due for installation next week!!) I'm using an Asus tinker board R2 with debian Buster. This is a steep learning curve in both Debian and Python. My strategy (grateful for ideas!) is to have the main control routine load a simple value into a text file when a sound effect is needed.

The sound routine polls the file every 0.5 second and if a valid value is found it plays the relevant mp3 sound file and resets the "semaphore". The idea is to avoid my main routine being blocked while the sound is playing.

If I call the playsound loop from a command line (python3 /home/scripts/runsound.py) it works beautifully, plays the sound and clears the semaphore. If I start runsound.py as a systemd service, it runs, and clears the semaphone, but no sound is produced. I've tried a few different strategies to initiate the sound action and they all do the same thing.

I've set up numerous tests to try and isolate what is going on.
The command:

```
sudo ffplay /home/carousel/sounds/4_StartBell.mp3 -autoexit -vn -acodec mp3
```

issued in a .ssh shell works.
The same line in a .sh script produces an error and fails:

> 'o codec could be found with name 'mp3

> Failed to open file '/home/carousel/sounds/4_StartBell.mp3' or configure filtergraph

I've read in some forums that there is a difference between issuing a command via a console and script, and ffplay may not be set up with needed environment variables.

Aother clue, if I remove the sudo -u root part from the above command line it finds the mp3 file but fails with the message:

> No protocol specified Could not initialize SDL - No available video
> device (Did you set the DISPLAY variable?)

The command also works if I use sudo -u linaro, which is a preconfigured account set up by Asus. If I clone this account, I assume duplicating group memberships and priveleges it does not work.

This all makes me think I'm not setting ffplay up correctly. I'd be very grateful for advice from those who know...

Comment: try `-nodisp`. probably `-vn` is not enough to make it work headlessly

Comment: Thanks Tom, tried that - the full set of options I'm using is: -autoexit -nodisp -loglevel quiet -vn.
The problem seems to be related to differences in system variables between a console login and a .sh or sstemd script. The ffplayer doesn't seem to find or be given acces to the correct environment.
I've found a numbers of ways to reliable break it, and a couple of ways to make ffplayer reliably run, but not from the script - no matter which login, sudo or su option is tried.